# C#: асинхронное чтение файла (кодировка )

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, text, async-await

Добрый день.

В целях самообразования поставил перед собой задачу: - есть текстовый файл, в который виндовс-сервис пишет в этот файл строки текста, поэтому я решил написать приложение, которое считывает данные с того файла синхронно, чтобы он не блокировался для сервиса.

**Код:**

```
 private async void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            dialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            dialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _fileName = tbFileName.Text = dialog.FileName;

                try
                {
                    rtbText.Text = await GetFileText();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }


        }

        async  Task<string> GetFileText()
        {
            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(_fileName,
                 FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                 bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
                int numRead;
                while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    //string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    string text = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    sb.Append(text);
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Loading complete...");
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Я столкнулся с такими проблемами:

1. Когда сервис пишет в файл, происходит ошибка (файл занят другим процессом)
2. Как определить кодировку файла считываемого файла?
3. Как узнать размер буфера (new byte[0x1000]), который мне потребуется для конкретного файла? Ведь файл постоянно увеличивается в размере

Прошу поделиться своими мыслями на этот счет.

Спасибо.

Comment: `FileShare.Read` - а сервису, который пишет, от этого плохо не становится? Может Write тоже разрешить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ваша программа должна быть готова к тому, что файл заблокирован, ловить соответствующее исключение и повторять попытку через определённый промежуток времени.
2. Никак. Для текстового файла кодировка должна быть известна наперёд. В формате текстового файла нет информации о кодировке, вы можете лишь с какой-то вероятностью попытаться угадать её без всяческих гарантий. Договаривайтесь с сервисом о том, в какой кодировке будет происходить запись в файл.
3. Проще всего читать файл через `ReadAllText`, и не заморачиваться с ручным управлением буферами. Чтение в буфер наперёд заданного размера может привести к «разрезанию» юникодного символа, например. Так что не создавайте самому себе сложности.

Comment: 2. А как же BOM?

Comment: @Qwertiy: BOM, кажется, бывает только в юникоде, и, кажется, только у Microsoft. Ну и он не обязателен.